# Input type text value cannot be updated via jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Below is the simple requirement in html, jQuery, servlet

Implementation: Forgot password module

1. Username text field and send button. --> OK
2. User enters username and press send button. --> Ok
3. Fire jquery on click event, post method --> OK
4. From DB get the security question for username --> OK
5. Get result in jquery call --> OK
6. display security question value in text field --> NOK

Some how I feel, the text field is updated and refreshed to old value.
so in my case,

step 1) Text value - placeholder property value

step 2) update from jQuery

step 3) again refreshed to placeholder property value

**jQuery**

```
$(document).on("click", "#btnuserName", function() {        
    $.post("/zmcwebadmin/ForgotPasswordServlet",function(securityQuestion) {     
        alert("I got the response in ajax "+ securityQuestion);//value is correct 
        $("input[type=text].txt_securityQuestion").val(securityQuestion);  //problem here
        console.log("txt_securityQuestion");    
    });
    });
```

**html**

```
<input type="text" id="ForgotPassUname" name="user_name" class="changepassformat"placeholder="Enter Username">

<button class="buttonformat" id="btnuserName"   name="btnuserName">SEND</button><br>

<input type="text" id="txt_securityQuestion" name="txt_securityQuestion" class="changepassformat" placeholder="Security Question"><br>

<input type="text" id="SecurityAns" name="SecurityAns" class="changepassformat" placeholder="Enter the Answer">
```

**Entire html code**

```
<body background="../Images/zebra_background.jpg">

<div id="header">
    <span style="float: left">ZMC Server </span> <img
        src="../Images/zebra_logo.png" width=150px height=50px
        style="float: right; padding-top: 5px">
    <form id="form_logout">
        <input type="image" class="logbuttonformat" id="logoutbtn"
        src="../Images/logout_deselected.png" onclick="changeLogoutImage()"
        alt="submit" style="padding: auto">
    </form>
</div>
<form  id="form_forgotpswd" >
<p  class="slectedNameformat"> FORGOT PASSWORD </p>
<input type="text" id="ForgotPassUname" name="user_name" class="changepassformat"placeholder="Enter Username">
<button class="buttonformat" id="btnuserName" name="btnuserName">SEND</button><br>
<input type="text" id="txt_securityQuestion" name="txt_securityQuestion" class="changepassformat">
<br>
<input type="text" id="SecurityAns" name="SecurityAns"class="changepassformat" placeholder="Enter the Answer">
<br><input type="button" class="buttonformat" value="SUBMIT">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Cross check selector `$("input[type=text].txt_securityQuestion")`;

Comment: @itzmukeshy7 thanks but it did not worked.

Comment: securityQuestion text field did not updated with the values received from servlet

Comment: share more code html and js may be after form post pare get refresh...

Comment: I have updated the entire html code snippet. the script part is already shared above.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107101/discussion-between-itzmukeshy7-and-school-boy).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need id selector instead of class selector here as `txt_securityQuestion` is id of element and not its class:

```
 $("#txt_securityQuestion").val(securityQuestion);
```

Comment: I tried but not working. I could see the textbox is updated with the value "securityQuestion" but then on next moment it got cleared automatically.

Comment: @SchoolBoy: do you have any code which sets this textboxes empty?

Comment: I think No, no body is making it empty.

Comment: alert is getting called only once.